# How to control the media and ringtone volumes separately?

Tags: volume-control

In my Galaxy S20, whenever I turn down the volume for an application, it also turns down the ringtone volume too, which means I'm missing calls if I forget to put the volume back up.

In my previous phone, when I would change the volume from within an application, that will change the "media", while if I was changing it from the home screen, that would change the "ringtone" volume. But now it seems if I change it from anywhere it changes both volumes.

Any idea how to make it work like before? I can't seem to find any option for this

Comment: For Samsung devices, have you checked the settings for "Use Volume keys for media" from Settings - Sounds and vibration - Volume? However, I'm not sure if there's a built-in/visual setting to revert to the previous behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to change media, system, ringtone, or notification. Just hit one of the volume keys, then when you see volume pop-up, should be a down arrow, just click that...